# Is there a derivative that uses a Rolling Release model?

Tags: derivatives

There were so many discussions about an Ubuntu with RR. They were so many pros and contras. At the end ubuntu wont be changed, the 6 month cycle system wont be changed. Thats fine!

But because there are so many people who would like to use an ubuntu with RR Im asking myself why isnt there an Ubuntu Derivate with RR. I couldnt found one, there are a loooot of Ubuntu Derivates but no RR. Is it just impossible? I mean Ubuntu = 6 months cycle, so the derivate have to be a 6 month cycle too? Is there no other option? Or are there already some smart guys trying to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I edited your title because of course anything is possible if someone does the work.

Comment: I am considering the possibility of creating a FULLY Rolling Release distro based on Ubuntu. This project will be sponsored & funded by my company Linux PC Plus. But in order to make this vision a reality, we need volunteers! We need developers, programmers, graphics designers, etc. If you are interested in contributing & being a part of this exciting project, please email wolf@linuxpcplus right away. Include a brief summary of your experience & why you want to be involved.

Comment: Why not just use Debian unstable ([sid](http://www.debian.org/releases/sid/))?

Comment: @LinuxPCplus Do you have a project page? You would probably benefit from presenting something showing clearly why it makes sense for people to contribute time and resources to *your particular project*.

Comment: Not yet Eliah, that is what I meant when I said more info will soon be available on my website. I am working on the project page now. As for why not use Debian unstable? While Ubuntu is based on Debian, it is NOT debian. There are some minor differences as you know. My goal for this yet to be named distro is make it as close to Ubuntu as possible, just rolling. My only real reason for posting this now is to see if there is enough interest in a Ubuntu RR to warrant the time & money that such an ambitious project would require.

Comment: Unfortunately, while I am a long time linux user & enthusiast, I lack much of the experience & knowledge to undertake this task. This means I must try to generate interest & find folks who do have the knowledge I do not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no official rolling release, all the supported Ubuntu derivative releases (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Edubuntu, Ubuntu Studio and Mythbuntu) are based on the Ubuntu release schedule, 6 months per released version and 1 LTS version every 2 years.

There are many rolling releases with unstable Debian based, ie:

- [Aptosid](http://aptosid.com/)
- [Linux Mint LMDE](http://linuxmint.com/)
- [AntiX](http://antix.mepis.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)

The closest that you will find from a rolling release supported by the Ubuntu base and using Ubuntu packages is +1, run it always on alpha or beta.

There is nothing wrong with assuming that Ubuntu +1 is something like a rolling release except for the fact that there is an EOL for the versions and once a version is released you have to force the system to use Ubuntu +1 again. It does not really fit the criteria for the name rolling release.

It's not a rolling release per se, but is the closest you will get.

Rolling releases (by definition) goes against what Ubuntu fights for every 6 months, basically before each release, packages are imported from Debian Unstable continuously and merged to the Ubuntu repos with modifications done for Ubuntu. A month before release, imports are frozen, and packagers then work to ensure that the frozen features interoperate well together.

Its a lot of work to be done and supply you with stable packages.

---

To move your system to the next release use the command `sudo update-manager -d`, it will allow you to install the packages from the future release

[image]

You will receive constant updates for this until the version is really released in April 2012, after that you will be able to apply the command again and update to the next future release after a couple of days.

Please note that this is not the intent of Ubuntu and that (as mostly any rolling release) the packages might break your system. If you are not so familiar with recovering a broken system this is not really advisable. Having said that I have to explain that depending on the skills some Ubuntu users "live" on Ubuntu +1 (mostly bug catchers and developers, but they exist).

In the end, it's up to you: the unstable world of Ubuntu +1 or the stable comfortable sight of updated stable packages every 6 months.

Comment: Hi. I know the "other" RR Distris like LMDE, Arch, Aptosid. These are nice but far away from ubuntu ^^. LMDE = buggy and I read that they have now companys who are paying them to change the software. Example with Firefox: if you do `apt-get install firefox`, you get a firefox without google searchbar just yahoo and amazon BECAUSE yahoo and amazon pay them money. And thats going on with a lot of other software there and HELL that sucks, LMDE failed. Aptosid is great, but its a little bit too "much" bleedig edge. Arch is great too, but nothing for "gui lovers" or linux-newbies ;)

Comment: Oh I forget my question to your post: "The closest that you will find from a rolling release supported by the Ubuntu base and using Ubuntu packages is +1, run it always on alpha or beta." - how to use this +1 on alpha/beta?

Comment: Added instructions for updating to Ubuntu +1, the reason LMDE is buggy is the same that there is no rr for Ubuntu, rr = buggy until fixed. One example from that atm is Arch Linux, famous, fast, geeky and last week broken. Thats the price you pay for rr.

Comment: I believe MX Linux (https://mxlinux.org/) uses rolling releases, too.

Answer (score 13):

Bruno's answer works but since that was made, there has been a new way to do it without the hassle.

From the Ubuntu GNOME Blog (works for **all** Ubuntu variants also!)

> There is a release called **devel**.
>
> If you put that in /etc/apt/sources.list instead of utopic/vivid etc, you will be kicked over the new devel version a few days after it opens.
>   No need to ever upgrade to the next version/release; just a dist-upgrade is enough.
>
> These days, the devel series are a bit stable, there are lots of automated testing, that makes sure everything is installable and passes tests before it propagates to the main archive. There is the odd issue that slips through the tests, but they get fixed quickly and while we wouldn’t recommend it for a full production system, the people that want the latest and greatest GNOME and tinker a bit, would be fine on it.
>
> This is how to edit /etc/apt/sources.list

1. Open /etc/apt/sources.list
2. Replace the codename of your installed Ubuntu (vivid, willy, etc.) with `devel`
3. Save and run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

> Once the next cycle starts, you don’t need to do anything except wait!

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu has ***Rolling Rhino***

If you want to read a blog about it, I'll refer you to

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/06/ubuntu-rolling-release-rhino-tool

> Ubuntu desktop lead Martin Wimpress has created a tool called Rolling Rhino. Its aim: convert an Ubuntu daily build image into a “rolling release” distro by opting into and tracking the devel series of changes/packages.   (*Joey Sneddon*)

or from the source directly

https://github.com/wimpysworld/rolling-rhino

> Convert Ubuntu into a "rolling release" that tracks the devel series; **for the toughest of Ubuntu users**.

Created by Martin Wimpress, (lead of Ubuntu Desktop at Canonical)

**WARNING**:

Using *Rolling Rhino* will put you off-topic for sites such as this, just like my own use of the *development* cycle does.  (I moved to
*groovy* the day after the release of *focal*, I'll move to the *h* series the day or so after *groovy* becomes 20.10, and I've been on the
*development* cycle since *artful* or before became 17.10, and know from experience problems can occur). You need to be aware that you'll have less support options using Rolling Rhino thus the warning given "***for the toughest of Ubuntu users***" should not be taken lightly !

Answer (score -4):

For now, you might want to try Bodhi Linux. It is a Partly Rolling Release & is Ubuntu based.

Comment: What does "Partly Rolling Release" mean?