# Ubuntu 13.10 gives me a black screen, should I use 12.04 instead?

Tags: system-installation

Hello reader I'm using HP 242 G1 laptop. Ubuntu was preinstalled in my laptop but I changed it to Windows 7 64 bit. I would like to switch back to Ubuntu.

Which one should I use, Ubuntu 12.04.3 or Ubuntu 13.10?

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 but after installation when I start my laptop the display turns black. Is there any sollution for that?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it for the black screen problem

Answer (score 0):

As user68186 commented [there is a fix for the black screen issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

Moreover, there is always a possibility that Ubutnu 12.04.3 will also have the black screen issue or some other issue.

Thus in deciding whether to use 12.04.03 you might also want to consider the fact that it is an LTS (Long term support) release and thus is guaranteed to be supported for 5 years after it's release, which is in April of 2017.

13.10 comes with the latest and greatest software, but it's support will end  9 months from it's release date which is July 2014.  Because of this you may want to choose a different [Ubuntu derivative that uses a rolling release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97861/is-there-a-derivative-that-uses-a-rolling-release-model).

So if having the most up to date software is most important to you, you likely should choose 13.10, where as if you would prefer not to need to update your operating system in 2 years, than 12.04.3 is likely a better choice.

See this [question for more on why Ubuntu limits support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168939/why-does-ubuntu-only-support-versions-for-a-limited-time-and-what-does-it-mean).

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is only good for 9 months!

Comment: @user68186 Wow, I did not realise Ubuntu shortened their support cycle for not LTS releases!!!  I will seriously consider LTS in the future.