# Ubuntu-based distro with a rolling release?

Tags: apt, debian, distro-recommendation

What Ubuntu-based distribution can you recommend which has a Rolling release model?
I want to have available both Ubuntu specific software (eg. Unity / Virtualbox / Snaps) and newer other software like from Debian Testing.
What do you think?
I want it to be a Ubuntu/Debian based distro, to be able to install .deb files.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, so distributions based on Ubuntu are off-topic here. ; Ubuntu-based are off-topic here.

Comment: What SX site can you recommend for this topic?

Comment: Reviewers:  I personally think my answer isn't opinion (being the only on-topic answer I think we can provide thus avoiding opinion), but am happy for comments if I'm wrong :)   (*my answer being off-topic or unwelcome would be more my concern... I've tried to provide some warning.. the comments/discussion made post-answer have I think added warning too*)

Comment: Duplicate - Yep will agree with that.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu has ***Rolling Rhino***

If you want to read a blog about it, I'll refer you to

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/06/ubuntu-rolling-release-rhino-tool

> Ubuntu desktop lead Martin Wimpress has created a tool called Rolling Rhino. Its aim: convert an Ubuntu daily build image into a “rolling release” distro by opting into and tracking the devel series of changes/packages.   (*Joey Sneddon*)

or from the source directly

https://github.com/wimpysworld/rolling-rhino

> Convert Ubuntu into a "rolling release" that tracks the devel series; for the toughest of Ubuntu users.

Created by Martin Wimpress, (lead of Ubuntu Desktop at Canonical)

Note:  Using *Rolling Rhino* will put you off-topic for sites such as this, just like my own use of the *development* cycle does (I moved to *groovy* the day after release of *focal*, i'll move to the *h* series the day or so after *groovy* becomes 20.10, so be aware that you'll have less support options using Rolling Rhino, thus the warning given *for the toughest of Ubuntu users*.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but the solution doesn't work for me. I get this: `ERROR: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS detected. Switching a LTS release to the devel series directly is not supported.`

Comment: You move to Rhino from the *development* release, ie. you need to move yourself to *groovy* first, then bump to *rhino*.  You've two steps to go, as stated at  https://github.com/wimpysworld/rolling-rhino '*that has been installed from a daily image into a "rolling release*"'.  You're currently on *stable* and need to bump to *daily* equivalent which currently is *groovy* (where I am), then you can *bump* to *rhino*

Comment: How can I update to groovy without downloading a new ISO? I have focal already installed.

Comment: Same as you upgrade a standard release, except you use the '-d' to move to an unstable release; eg. read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes and read the "*Upgrading from..*" section. There are two commands, one for servers (`sudo do-release-upgrade -d`) and one for desktops (`update-manager -c -d`)

Comment: **Please take note of the warning**... If you're needing this help, in my opinion, you're not really ready for *rhino*, as the loss of support sites like this will impact you if/when you have problems (development cycles are off-topic).  I installed my current system when *artful* was still in development (ie. before it was 17.10) and I've had issues on occasion, they are rare - but they do happen. You need to be able to deal with them when they occur (you won't be able to come and ask here etc)

Comment: Thank you for your support, I now understand the process

Comment: I think the Warning should perhaps be a bit more bold and perhaps closer to the top of the answer.

Comment: This is not a rolling release like other OS provide. It should not be used as daily driver unless you can handle a ton of issues, it is still a development version.

Comment: @guiverc Would you like to post an answer here https://askubuntu.com/q/97861/816190?

Comment: ack @Kulfy, done.  Warning made more significant (not moved to top, but thanks Ian

Comment: Excellent. Thanks :)